# Oracle Regexp fails in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to use this regexp statement:

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('040', '^[\d\*]{3}$');
```

No output is returned but interesting to say:

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('040', '^[[:digit:]\*]{3}$');
```

works.

Why?

I am on Oracle 11.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you're using a POSIX character class. In your first example you're mixing POSIX and ['Perl-influenced extensions'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#sthref553). The [matching character-list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#r9c1-t7) enclosed in `[ ... ]`:

> Matches any single character in the list within the brackets. The following operators are allowed within the list, but other metacharacters included are treated as literals ...

So within the `[]`, the backslash metacharacter is treated as a literal backslash, which you're looking for any of the characters `\`, `d` or `*`, and *not* for a single digit as you expect - the `\d` just isn't interpreted like that within the brackets. And you don't have any of those literal characters in your sample string, therefore it doesn't find a match.

Even in your second version, the `\*` is only going to match those literal characters too, so that isn't adding anything; unless you want to match a value like `'12*'` or `'1\2'`, which seems unlikely.

So you may just want the simpler:

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('040', '^\d{3}$');
```

or the equivalent:

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('040', '^[[:digit:]]{3}$');
```

Comment: The citation explains the behavior, I need to modify my statement to `'^[[:digit:]*]{3}$'` because I need to be able to match stuff like `040*` too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is because Oracle only supports the POSIX regular expressions standard, rather than the Perl syntax that you use in your first example.

Oracle Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDJGBGG
POSIX Regex Standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/re.html

Edit: As [Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole) points out Oracle does actually support Perl regex syntax since Oracle 10gR2. Trying your example on my local 11gR2 install suggests that your syntax is wrong, the following works fine:

`SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE regexp_like('040', '^\d{3}$');`

Comment: Oracle supports ['Perl-influenced extenstions'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#sthref553) too though.